# Unable to run Presto LDAPS from SQL workbench

Tags: ssl, ldap, amazon-emr, presto, sql-workbench-j

I am unable to execute any query from **Sql-workbench/J for AWS-EMR presto which is Ldaps(SSL/secureLDAP) enabled**. Following are the details:

```
Connection String:  jdbc:presto://hostname:8446/hive?SSL=true   
username=admin
password=****
```

I can connect to it successfully, but while executing any query (let say..show tables), it throws error:

> An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
>   show tables
>   Error executing query
>   1 statement failed.
>   Execution time: 0.95s

These are the configurations:
**AWS Conf:**

```
Release label:emr-5.10.0
Hadoop distribution:Amazon 2.7.3
Applications:Presto 0.187,Tez 0.8.4, Hive 2.3.1, Ganglia 3.7.2
machines:
Master:m4.2xlarge
Core:m4.2xlarge
```

**Config.properties:**

```
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
discovery.uri=http://hostname:8889
http-server.threads.max=500
discovery-server.enabled=true
sink.max-buffer-size=1GB
query.max-memory=300GB
query.max-memory-per-node=8GB
query.max-history=40
query.min-expire-age=30m
http-server.http.port=8889
http-server.log.path=/var/log/presto/http-request.log
http-server.log.max-size=67108864B
http-server.log.max-history=5
log.max-size=268435456B
log.max-history=5
query.client.timeout = 40m
distributed-index-joins-enabled = yes
optimizer.optimize-metadata-queries = true

#---LDAP Properties-------------
http-server.authentication.type=LDAP
authentication.ldap.url=ldaps://ldap.server:636

http-server.https.enabled=true
http-server.https.port=8446

authentication.ldap.user-base-dn=DC=int,DC=domain,DC=com
authentication.ldap.user-bind-pattern=${USER}@int.domain.com
authentication.ldap.group-auth-pattern=(&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=${USER})(memberof=CN=GroupNAme,OU=Groups,OU=Root,DC=int,DC=domain,DC=com))

http-server.https.keystore.path=/etc/presto/CA.keystore
http-server.https.keystore.key=changeit
```

**Node.properties**

```
node.environment=production
node.id=i-0dddcd9cff07367f4
node.data-dir=/var/lib/presto/data
catalog.config-dir=/etc/presto/conf/catalog
plugin.dir=/usr/lib/presto/plugin
```

**catalog/hive.properties:**

```
hive.s3.connect-timeout=2m
hive.s3.max-backoff-time=10m
hive.s3.max-error-retries=50
hive.metastore-refresh-interval=1m
hive.s3.max-connections=500
hive.s3.max-client-retries=50
connector.name=hive-hadoop2
hive.s3.socket-timeout=2m
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://IP:9083
hive.metastore-cache-ttl=20m
hive.s3.staging-directory=/mnt/tmp
hive.s3.use-instance-credentials=true
hive.non-managed-table-writes-enabled = true
hive.config.resources=/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml,/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml
```

The Presto LDAPS is working fine from presto-cli.

What am I missing?

Comment: Any luck with this? I ran into the same issue.